# How to save the sorted series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am trying to save my pandas series:

```
arr = [81, 9, 3, 42, 6, 4]
data = pd.Series(arr)
print(data.sort_values())
```

Result:

```
2     3
5     4
4     6
1     9
3    42
0    81
```

But when I try to get the first element:

```
arr = [81, 9, 3, 42, 6, 4]
data = pd.Series(arr)
X = data.sort_values()
print(X[0])
```

I get:

```
81
```

But I am looking to save the sorted array, i.e., I should get 3 (the smallest value).

Comment: need `print (X.iloc[0])` or `print (X.iat[0])`

Comment: It works, Thanks alot